# axWindowsMediaPlayer playlist pause (c#)

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm using axWindowsMediaPlayer playlist, and have some problem - after one video end's - next playing without any pause. I cant pause or stop it even with

```
 private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_MediaChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MediaChangeEvent e)
    {

         if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded) 
         {axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause(); }}
```

It doesn't do anything, but must stop the player. What can I do with this? Or even disable AUTOplaying next playlist file, that's would be even better. 
Thx a lot for help!

Comment: WMP is fickle, these kind of "progress changed" events (PlayStateChange too) were only meant to update your own UI.  You cannot use them to change the player state.  You have to issue the command later, after the event returned.   Trivially done in, say, a Winforms app by using the form's BeginInvoke() method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be working with the object passed into the method and additionally the PlayStateChange event like so:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e) 
{
    if (e.newState == 8) 
    {
        e.Ctlcontrols.pause();
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE: Also I would suggest that you use the axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChanged() event rather than Media change as this may be where the issue is occurring.

The '8' is to signify "Media Ended" which if you know how to access it another way then you of course can. If you want to use WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded I'm sure it would yeild the same result.

Comment: Thanks! But can you give some addinional info? I cant use e.playState in axWindowsMediaPlayer1_MediaChange or axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange. Then in what event I can use this?

Comment: Please see my edit, you should be able to use e.newState and this will be within the PlayStateChanged event.

Comment: if (e.newState == 8)           {                            }  Work's fine,but e.Ctlcontrols.pause(); - no. Error CS1061. axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause(); - compiling, but no effect.

Comment: Yes, what about that?

Comment: Ah okay I see. When the media ends, is it going inside that if statement?

Comment: Yes, MessageBox.show working, but dont working any commands axWindowsMediaPlayer